# Hide unused control event

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Using VS 2015 with WinForms I have double clicked on a control and brought up it's default Sub event. I'll never have to write code in this event but now it's there taking up space. I deleted it and when I double clicked on it again nothing happened. However, when I went back into my code I noticed it was indeed re-created.

Now, if I was to ever have to write code in this control I can no longer double click on it. I know I can right click and choose View Code but what I'm wondering is if I did something wrong. Should I just leave the unused event routine there and just collapse it (click on the -+), or is there a better, more efficient way to hide an unused control event?

Thanks...

Comment: This is functionality i've seen a lot, it's just how Visual Studio attempts to remember what it has mapped. If you remove the event handler in the code it may not know and when you double click it will try to go to it's map, fail and create it. A usual fix to this is just to restart visual studio :)

Comment: In a WPF app you can still delete the unused handler but you will have to edit the XML is match.

Comment: Thanks Mary but this is WinForms. I have updated my question to include that.

Comment: If you click the button in the designer it will recreate the function again.  You  can safely delete it or just hide it using the -+.  You can also try adding code you want hidden inside of a #Region "Code for Later"

Comment: Thanks for your input. If\when I delete it and someone else comes along and needs to actually code in it they may wonder why double clicking doesn't work. But knowing that deleting it won't harm anything is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to the properties (F4) events tab, try Rick-clicking on the event you want removed, and selecting "Reset".

I think doing this should work:

[image]

Comment: This is great to know, however, for my problem it didn't work.